# ¿Cómo puedo habilitar GETs a la API sin un token de JWT?

Tags: jquery, nodejs, jwt

Tengo una APP en NodeJs y la seguridad está regida por JWT.

El problema que tengo es que necesito acceder a esta APP para hacer consultas desde una web con Wordpress vía jQuery.

¿Cómo puedo habilitar estos GETs a la API sin un token de JWT? o ¿qué otra metodología se puede utilizar?

Comment: ¿que package jwt estas ocupando (jsonwebtoken, jwt-simple)?

Comment: Hola @LuisAngelMezaPerez estyo utilizando "jsonwebtoken": "^6.2.0".

Comment: ¿estas aplicando el jsonwebtoken para todas las url (request)?

Comment: @LuisAngelMezaPerez Si, excepto el post de /authenticate.

Comment: ¿puedes colocar algún ejemplo básico de como lo estas implementando por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opción A**

Crea un método que no requiera autenticación y que puedas consumir. En donde tengas tus métodos para consumir tu api agrega uno nuevo:

```
app.get('/mi-ruta-sin-autenticacion', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({ message: 'Hola :o' })
})
```

O usando arrow function:

```
app.get('/mi-ruta-sin-autenticacion', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({ message: 'Hola :o' })
})
```

O mejor aún, separando las funciones a ejecutar:

```
const controller = require('../controllers/micontroller')
app.get('/mi-ruta-sin-autenticacion', controller.metodo)
```

**Opción B**
Considera quitar la validación del JWT en las rutas que ya existen, a menos que tu api sea consumida por otros recursos entonces quizá lo mejor sea la opción A. Sólo ten en cuenta que no estará protegida.

**Opción C**
Desde Php crea un JWT: https://github.com/auth0/php-jwt-example
esa doc y ejemplo te pueden servir. Sólo debes instalar la extensión de JWT en el servidor donde está alojado tu Wordpress, no sé qué tanto control tengas a él. En caso de que no puedas instalar la extension JWT, esta opción queda descartada.

Comment: Hay un tema que no quedó muy bien explicado. Necesito identificar la conexión. Quiero que solo ese wordpress se conecte y no que cualquiera pueda acceder a la APP.. Estuve leyendo algo sobre privates keys, pero no entendí muy bien como hacerlo.